# Boolean coercion in Javascript 'if' guards

Tags: javascript, boolean, coercion

I noticed this behavior in Javascript today which has me thoroughly surprised and confused:

```
if ("0") {
    console.log('first')
}
if ("0" == true) {
    console.log('second');
}
```

output:

```
first
```

I would have expected either both or neither of the `console.log` lines to execute. I had always believed that the contents of a guard is evaluated, coerced into a boolean, and then passes or fails based on the value of this boolean. This would result in both of the guards above being equivalent, but the observed behavior indicates something else is going on.

How does Javascript determine whether a guard passes or fails?

Comment: `== true` does not coerce to a boolean, it coerces both parts to a number.

Comment: Only `Boolean(…)` is equivalent to `Boolean(…) == true`

Comment: @Bergi: why do both parts get coerced into a number if neither is a number to begin with?

Comment: Because numbers are a good middle way? I don't know, that's just how it works. If you don't want coercion but just fail to `false` for different types, use `===`.

Comment: So `==` in Javascript always coerces both sides into a number regardless of their types? Or is it just because one of the sides was "number-like"?

Comment: I was only referring to the case where one of the operands is a boolean. You can read the full algorithm [here](http://es5.github.io/#x11.9.3)